# I have some problems with NDSolve, my ODE is about Dynamics of Robot mechanism, and my BVP cannot be solved by NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, warning-messages, boundary-condition-at-infinity

[image: Position control of a 3DoF planar manipulator]
Here are the parameters which are given in the task

```
g = 9.81;
h = 0.009;
m1 = 4.5;
m2 = 4.25;
m3 = 3.3;
L2 = 1.2;
L3 = 0.8;
\[Theta]CoM1 = 0.2;
```

Matrixes of the transforms

```
T01 = ({
{1, 0, 0, q1[t]},
{0, 1, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 1, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 1}
});

T12 = ({
{Cos[q2[t]], -Sin[q2[t]], 0, 0},
{Sin[q2[t]], Cos[q2[t]], 0, 0},
{0, 0, 1, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 1}
});

T23 = ({
{Cos[q3[t]], -Sin[q3[t]], 0, L2},
{Sin[q3[t]], Cos[q3[t]], 0, 0},
{0, 0, 1, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 1}
});

T02 = T01.T12;

T03 = T02.T23;
```

Total cebtre point

```
r3TCP = ({
{L3},
{0},
{0},
{1}
});
```

centrals of masses

```
r1CoM1 = ({
{0},
{0},
{0},
{1}
});
r2CoM2 = ({
{L2/2},
{0},
{0},
{1}
});
r3CoM3 = ({
{L3/2},
{0},
{0},
{1}
});
r0TCP = T03.r3TCP ;
r0CoM1 = T01.r1CoM1 ;
r0CoM2 = T02.r2CoM2 ;
r0CoM3 = T03.r3CoM3 ;
```

velocities

```
vCoM1 = D[r0CoM1, t];  // Simplify
vCoM2 = D[r0CoM2, t];  // Simplify
vCoM3 = D[r0CoM3, t];  // Simplify

\[Phi]1 = 0;
\[Phi]2 = \[Phi]1 + q2[t];
\[Phi]3 = \[Phi]2 + q3[t];
\[Omega]1 = D[\[Phi]1, t];
\[Omega]2 = D[\[Phi]2, t];
\[Omega]3 = D[\[Phi]3, t];
```

given initial parameters

```
qD1 = 0.5;
qD2 = 35 \[Pi]/180;
qD3 = 50 \[Pi]/180;
qDsubs = {q1[t] -> qD1, q2[t] -> qD2, q3[t] -> qD3};
r0TCP /. qDsubs 
r0CoM1 /. qDsubs;
r0CoM2 /. qDsubs
r0CoM3 /. qDsubs

\[Theta]CoM3 = 1/12*m3*L3^2
\[Theta]CoM2 = 1/12*m2*L2^2
```

Function U and T

```
U = g (m1*r0CoM1[[1, 1]] + m2*r0CoM2[[1, 1]] + m3*r0CoM3[[1, 1]]) // 
Simplify

T = 0.5 (m1*vCoM1\[Transpose].vCoM1 + m2*vCoM2\[Transpose].vCoM2 + 
 m3*vCoM3\[Transpose].vCoM3 + \[Theta]CoM1*\[Omega]1^2 + \
\[Theta]CoM2*\[Omega]2^2 + \[Theta]CoM3*\[Omega]3^2) // Simplify
```

ODEs

```
Eq1 = (D[D[T, q1'[t]], t] - D[T, q1[t]] + D[U, q1[t]])[[1, 1]];
Eq2 = (D[D[T, q2'[t]], t] - D[T, q2[t]] + D[U, q2[t]])[[1, 1]];
Eq3 = (D[D[T, q3'[t]], t] - D[T, q3[t]] + D[U, q3[t]])[[1, 1]];
```

MassMatrix

```
M = ({
{Coefficient[Eq1, q1''[t]], Coefficient[Eq1, q2''[t]], 
Coefficient[Eq1, q3''[t]]},
{Coefficient[Eq2, q1''[t]], Coefficient[Eq2, q2''[t]], 
Coefficient[Eq2, q3''[t]]},
{Coefficient[Eq3, q1''[t]], Coefficient[Eq3, q2''[t]], 
Coefficient[Eq3, q3''[t]]}
})

MqD = M /. qDsubs; MqD // MatrixForm

Cq = ({
 {Eq1},
 {Eq2},
 {Eq3}
}) - M.({
  {q1''[t]},
  {q2''[t]},
  {q3''[t]}
 });

CqD = Cq /. qDsubs ; CqD // MatrixForm 

solutionFreemotion = NDSolve[{({{Eq1},{Eq2},{Eq3}}) == {0, 0, 0}, q1[0] == 
0.4, q2[0] == 0, q3[0] ==0, 
q1'[0] == 0, q2'[0] == 0, q3'[0] == 0}, {q1[t], q2[t], q3[t], 
q1'[t], q2'[t], q3'[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, StartingStepSize -> h, 
Method -> {"FixedStep", 
Method -> "EquationSimplification\[Rule]Residual"}]

Fig2 = Plot[(T + U) /. solutionFreemotion, {t, 0, 100}];
Fig3 = Plot[q1[t] /. solutionFreemotion, {t, 0, 100}];
Fig4 = Plot[q2[t] /. solutionFreemotion, {t, 0, 100}];
Fig5= Plot[q3[t] /. solutionFreemotion, {t, 0, 100}];
Show[Fig2, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t[s]", "T+U [J]"}, 
GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 150}}]
Show[Fig3, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t[s]", "q_1 [rad]"}, 
GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large]
Show[Fig4, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t[s]", "q_2 [rad]"}, 
GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large]
Show[Fig5, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t[s]", "q_3 [m]"}, 
GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large]

p = 1/27
d = 17/57
kp = p/h^2
kd = d/h
H = IdentityMatrix[3]
KP = kp*IdentityMatrix[3]
KD = kd*IdentityMatrix[3]
uPD = -KP.({
  {q1[t] - qD1},
  {q2[t] - qD2},
  {q3[t] - qD3}
 }) - KD.({
 {q1'[t]},
 {q2'[t]},
 {q3'[t]}
 })
EQ = ({
{Eq1},
{Eq2},
{Eq3}
 })

solutionPD = 
NDSolve[{EQ[[1, 1]] - H.uPD[[1, 1]] == 0, 
EQ[[2, 1]] - H.uPD[[2, 1]] == 0, EQ[[3, 1]] - H.uPD[[3, 1]] == 0, 
q1[0] == 0.4, q2[0] == 0, q3[0] == 0, q1'[0] == 0, q2'[0] == 0, 
q3'[0] == 0}, {q1[t], q2[t], q3[t], q1'[t], q2'[t], q3'[t]}, {t, 0,
10}, StartingStepSize -> h, 
Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "Automatic"}]
Fig6 = Plot[q1[t] /. solutionPD, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, \[Pi]/3}];
Fig7 = Plot[q2[t] /. solutionPD, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, \[Pi]/3}];
Fig8 = Plot[q3[t] /. solutionPD, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, \[Pi]/3}];
Fig9 = Plot[uPD[[1]] /. solutionPD, {t, 0, 5}, 
PlotRange -> {-700, 700}];
Fig10 = Plot[uPD[[2]] /. solutionPD, {t, 0, 5}, 
PlotRange -> {-200, 200}];
Fig11 = Plot[uPD[[3]] /. solutionPD, {t, 0, 5}, 
PlotRange -> {-300, 300}];
Show[Fig6, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t[s]", "q1[t]"}, 
GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large]
Show[Fig7, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t[s]", "q2[t]"}, 
GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large]
 Show[Fig8, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t[s]", "q3[t]"}, 
GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large]
Show[Fig9, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t[s]", "u1[t]"}, 
GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large]
Show[Fig10, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t[s]", "u2[t]"}, 
GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large]
Show[Fig11, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t[s]", "u3[t]"}, 
GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large]
```

I have this part of code, according to my homework about Dynamics of Robotmechanism, im facing to this problem.
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.
I have the same problem in PD controlled task.
I hope you can understand my problem now.
I added the plotting. These are the diagrams I need.
Thanks
Vitya

Comment: Functions $T, U$ are not defined.

Comment: Sorry, they are defined, just my code is long, so I didnt wanted to copy the whole of it.

Comment: You could give a minimal working example with `T, U`, also it is better to show definition as it is.

Comment: Edited it thank you

Comment: Remarks to the model used. First, mass M2 (and M3) rotate not around of center of mass, but around center of coordinate system highlighted on the picture. Therefore   parameters $\theta CoM2 , \theta CoM3$ should be revised. Second, `T, U` can be derived by very simple way with using kinematic model.

Answer (score 4):

Short version of code for this model based on picture uploaded

```
g = 9.81; 
m1 = 4.5; 
m2 = 4.25; 
m3 = 3.3; 
L2 = 1.2; 
L3 = 0.8; 

r1 = {q1[t], 0}; r2 = {q1[t] + L2/2 Cos[q2[t]], 
  L2/2 Sin [q2[t]]}; r3 = {q1[t] + L2 Cos[q2[t]] + 
   L3/2 Cos[q3[t] + q2[t]], L2 Sin[q2[t]] + L3/2 Sin[q2[t] + q3[t]]};

T = (m1/2 D[r1, t] . D[r1, t] + m2/2 D[r2, t] . D[r2, t] + 
     m3/2 D[r3, t] . D[r3, t] + I2 D[q2[t], t]^2/2 + 
     I3 D[q3[t] + q2[t], t]^2/2) /. {I2 -> m2 L2^2/12, 
    I3 -> m3 L3^2/12};

U = r2 . {0, g} + r3 . {0, g};

Eq1 = (D[D[T, Derivative[1][q1][t]], t] - D[T, q1[t]] + D[U, q1[t]]); 
Eq2 = (D[D[T, Derivative[1][q2][t]], t] - D[T, q2[t]] + D[U, q2[t]]); 
Eq3 = (D[D[T, Derivative[1][q3][t]], t] - D[T, q3[t]] + D[U, q3[t]]); 

sol = NDSolve[{Eq1 == 0, Eq2 == 0, Eq3 == 0, q1[0] == 0.4, q2[0] == 0,
    q3[0] == 0, q1'[0] == 0, q2'[0] == 0, q3'[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[q1[t] == 0, end = t; "StopIntegration"]}, {q1[t], q2[t], 
   q3[t], q1'[t], q2'[t], q3'[t]}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

Visualization

```
var = {q1, q2, q3, q1', q2', q3'};

Table[Plot[var[[i]][t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 20}, PlotLabel -> var[[i]],
   Frame -> True], {i, 6}]

Plot[(T + U) /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Second part of this project

```
p = 1./27;
d = 17./57; h = 0.009;
kp = p/h^2;
kd = d/h; qD1 = 0.5;
qD2 = 35. Pi/180;
qD3 = 50. Pi/180;
H = IdentityMatrix[3];
KP = kp*IdentityMatrix[3];
KD = kd*IdentityMatrix[3];
uPD = -KP . ({{q1[t] - qD1}, {q2[t] - qD2}, {q3[t] - qD3}}) - 
  KD . ({{q1'[t]}, {q2'[t]}, {q3'[t]}}); HuPD = H . uPD;

{b, m} = CoefficientArrays[{Eq1 - HuPD[[1, 1]] == 0, 
   Eq2 - HuPD[[2, 1]] == 0, Eq3 - HuPD[[3, 1]] == 0}, {q1''[t], 
   q2''[t], q3''[t]}];
eq = -Inverse[m] . b;
solPD = NDSolve[{q1''[t] == eq[[1]], q2''[t] == eq[[2]], 
   q3''[t] == eq[[3]], q1[0] == 0.4, q2[0] == 0, q3[0] == 0, 
   q1'[0] == 0, q2'[0] == 0, q3'[0] == 0}, {q1[t], q2[t], q3[t], 
   q1'[t], q2'[t], q3'[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Visualization

```
{Table[Plot[var[[i]][t] /. solPD[[1]], {t, 0, 10}, 
   PlotLabel -> var[[i]], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All], {i, 3}], 
 Plot[uPD[[1]] /. solPD[[1]], {t, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> "uPD[[1]]", PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[uPD[[2]] /. solPD[[1]], {t, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> "uPD[[2]]", PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[uPD[[3]] /. solPD[[1]], {t, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> "uPD[[3]]", PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: I had have such a wrong solution, but the graphs should have a constant values, first graph is an Energy which should havew a constant value.

Comment: Energy is `T+U`, first plot is `q1`, and `q1,q2,q3` are coordinates in this model. To plot energy please use `Plot[(T + U) /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 100}]`. In this plot energy slightly deviates from the initial value.

Comment: I did, but it is bullshit. The values aren't correct, the energy cant be 0J, a robotmechanism can't do this oscillating rotation and a slider cant do this as shown in q1[m].

Comment: Hm... There is nothing in numerical result more than you proposed in your model. Where did you take this model?

Comment: I made the model based on the lectures and seminars. My friend did the same and his solution works. He has another model, but the whole problem is the same, just another coordinates

Comment: Here forum about Mathematica usage, not about robot models. Also I am not an expert in robot mechanics. But one question I have concerning your model. What for you evaluate `r0TCP /. qDsubs; r0CoM1 /. qDsubs;  r0CoM2 /. qDsubs; r0CoM3 /. qDsubs;`?

Comment: The locations in the 0th coordinate system of the TCP and the centrals of mass.

Comment: I know its about Mathematica usage, but it's a bug in the program. The problem is not in my model.

Comment: No, I think that the problem in your model. Can you explain what do you try to describe?

Comment: I uploaded a picture

Comment: Shot -> Short?  +1 in any case!

Comment: @chris Thank you, edited shot to short. :)

Comment: I found the indexing problem and now it works perfect, but another problem I have with it, can you please check it? I edited the question.

Comment: @Vitya See update to my answer. Pay attention, that my model derived from the picture uploaded.

Comment: My code doesn't want to plot the good solution, can you please share your code?

Comment: It works now perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

About the dynamic modeling

```
J2 = 1/12*m2*L2^2;
J3 = 1/12*m3*L3^2;
p1 = {q1[t], 0};
p2 = p1 + L2/2 {Cos[q2[t]], Sin[q2[t]]};
p3 = p1 + L2 {Cos[q2[t]], Sin[q2[t]]} + L3/2 {Cos[q2[t] + q3[t]], Sin[q2[t] + q3[t]]};
v1 = D[p1, t]
v2 = D[p2, t]
v3 = D[p3, t]
omega2 = D[q2[t], t]
omega3 = D[q2[t] + q3[t], t]
T = 1/2 (m1 v1.v1 + m2 v2.v2 + m3 v3.v3) + 1/2 (J2 omega2^2 + J3 omega3^2)
U = g (m2 p2 + m3 p3).{0, 1}
L = T - U
vars = {q1[t], q2[t], q3[t]};
equs = D[Grad[L, D[vars, t]], t] - Grad[L, vars]
cinits = {q1[0] == 0.4, q2[0] == q3[0] == q1'[0] == q2'[0] == q3'[0] == 0};
ODE = Join[Thread[equs == 0], cinits];
tmax = 10;
sol = NDSolve[ODE, vars, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]]
Table[Plot[vars[[k]] /. sol, {t, 0, tmax}], {k, 1, 3}]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

And with control

```
p = 1/27;
d = 17/57;
h = 0.009;
kp = p/h^2;
kd = d/h;
qD1 = 0.5;
qD2 = 35. Pi/180;
qD3 = 50. Pi/180;
H = IdentityMatrix[3];
KP = kp*IdentityMatrix[3];
KD = kd*IdentityMatrix[3];
uPD = -KP.({{q1[t] - qD1}, {q2[t] - qD2}, {q3[t] - qD3}}) - KD.({{q1'[t]}, {q2'[t]}, {q3'[t]}});
HuPD = Flatten[H.uPD];
CLODE = Join[Thread[equs == HuPD], cinits];
sol = NDSolve[CLODE, vars, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
qDs = {qD1, qD2, qD3};
Table[Plot[{vars[[k]] /. sol, qDs[[k]]}, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All], {k, 1, 3}]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice approach (+1).  Why do you take initial data are differ from that in the Vitya post?

Comment: Good question. Well, I would swear that the initial conditions of the question, they were the ones I used. There was a recent edit to the text of the question ... Any way, I will prepare according to the new conditions.

Comment: But in the second part Vitya used the same initial condition `q1[0] == 0.4, q2[0] == 0, q3[0] == 0, 
   q1'[0] == 0, q2'[0] == 0, q3'[0] == 0`.

Comment: I did the corrections. Now looks good.